# Bad practice - Making fragment use objects from Activity?

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

Is it bad practice to make a fragment use objects from its holder activity or should I make each of my fragments initialize their own objects.

The reason I think it's bad practice is because now the fragment is dependent on an activity and this takes away its reusability. Please tell me what is best practice for using fragments.

For example, I have an Activity MainActivity which has a navigation drawer. The navigation drawer is used to switch between five fragments in the MainActivity. In the MainActivity, I have initialized:

```
public class MainActivity extends SherlockFragmentActivity {

private DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;
private ListView mDrawerList;
private ActionBarDrawerToggle mDrawerToggle;
private ArrayList<String> navItems;
private NavigationAdapter navAdapter;
private ArrayList<Series> series;
private ArrayList<Episode> history;
private ArrayList<NewsItem> news;
FlowAdapter flowAdapter;
CardAdapter cardAdapter;
NewsAdapter newsAdapter;
Server SP = new Server();
Processor CPU = new Processor();
Parser mParser = new Parser();
...
}
```

And in one of my fragments, which is called HomeFragment, I'm wondering if it were to be better to initialize its own version of each of the objects:

```
public class HomeFragment extends SherlockFragment implements
    OnNavigationListener {

GridView homeList;
ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> modeList;
ActionBar mActionBar;
int current_item;
SherlockFragmentActivity main;
private ArrayList<Series> series;
FlowAdapter flowAdapter;
Bundle savedInstanceState;
ImageFetcher mFetcher;
boolean flag_loading;
Server SP = new Server();
Processor CPU = new Processor();
int page;
...
}
```

... or to get them from the MainActivity by using some function like:

```
@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    SP = ((MainActivity) getActivity()).getServer();
...
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best practice on linking Activity and Fragment is using callbacks. For example, let's imagine you want take some objects from the hosting `Activity` and use them at the your `Fragment`. It's obvious, that in such a case `Activity` should have some functionality to satisfy `Fragment`. Thus, we can use interfaces.

```
public interface MyCallback {
    Object takeObject();
}
```

Then, make `Activity` to implement this interface:

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity implements MyCallback {

}
```

After that, you can save a link to this `Activity` at the `onAttach` callback:

```
public class MyFragment extends Fragment {

    MyCallback callback;

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
        try {
            callback = (MyCallback) activity;
        } catch (ClassCastException ex){
            throw new ClassCastException("Hosting activity must implement " 
               + MyCallback.class.getSimpleName());
        }
        super.onAttach(activity);
    }
}
```

Later in code you can use this callback as following:

```
if (callback != null){
    Object object = callback.takeObject();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using interfaces for communication is not best way. Check my similar answer here @ https://stackoverflow.com/a/25976762/1677824 . It talks about **otto** an event bus android library for communication.